# How to play a youtube video from a specific second to another specific second?

Tags: javascript, youtube-iframe-api

I know there are start and end url query params when you share the link for a youtube video so the video starts and ends at those seconds.

I want to do the same with javascript using the Youtube Iframe Player API.
I know there is the method player.getCurrentTime() that returns the elapsed time in seconds since the video started playing.

There is no event fired when the current time changes.

Comment: Maybe start/end get parameters? There are alot of articles.

Comment: @bigless That does not work with javascript.

Comment: I can't understand your question... You want to have a form with 2 inputs for example : start time - end time, and a button that triggers it?
If not, please explain your question

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what kind of answer you need,

But here is two examples:

1. Simple IFrame from youtube share

   https://www.youtube.com/embed/YourVideoID?start=**startSeconds**&end=**EndSeconds**
2. IFrame API: you can check out IFrame API Docs here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

From there you can see that you can load video from id using Argument Syntax or Object syntax

I prefer using objects. But here is both:

**Argument Syntax**

```
player.loadVideoById(videoId: String,
                     startSeconds: Number): Void
```

**Object Syntax**

```
player.loadVideoById({ videoId: String,
                       startSeconds: Number,
                       endSeconds: Number}): Void
```

You can also try it out from the example tab: https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo

Your question is not really clear so if something is missing please reply and I will be happy to edit my answer.